# How to combine all rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE oB 

--Consent for release of Insurance Information--
SELECT 
    a.objectID,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(a.attr1397)) 'LastName',
    LTRIM(RTRIM(a.attr1395)) 'FirstName',
    LTRIM(RTRIM(a.attr1400)) 'ID',
    LTRIM(RTRIM(b.attr1624)) 'Car Name',
    LTRIM(RTRIM(b.attr1626)) 'Pol Number'
FROM 
    dbo.nstance1029 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.nstance1048 b ON a.objectid = b.fk16
```

Which produces this:

[image]

How can I modify the query so for each `a.objectID/LastName/FirstName/ID The Car Name/Pol Name` appears in the same row instead of multiple rows?

Comment: Ando *how* must the multiple car names pol numbers be combined in a single row? concatenated or what? please add details.

Comment: What about the policy number?  Looks like there are different values for any given objectid/etc.

Comment: Read up on pivot tables and `for xml`

Comment: The `Car Name` and `Pol Name` should be a column across instead of different rows

Comment: Search this site for `[sql-server] pivot tables` (including the square brackets). This is only about the 500th question asking the same thing here.

Comment: Based on the information above by using cross apply (instead of join) with nstance1048 table and non null validation within the where clause should provide desire results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross apply will be some thing like this:

```
SELECT 
        a.objectID,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(a.attr1397)) 'LastName',
        LTRIM(RTRIM(a.attr1395)) 'FirstName',
        LTRIM(RTRIM(a.attr1400)) 'ID',
        temp.cars 'Car Name',
        temp.PolNumber 'Pol Number'
    FROM 
        dbo.nstance1029 a 
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(b.attr1624))  + ','
        FROM nstance1048  AS b
        WHERE a.objectid  = b.fk16  
        FOR XML PATH('')) 
        temp(cars)
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(b.attr1626)) + ','
        FROM nstance1048 AS b
        WHERE a.objectid =  b.fk16
        FOR XML PATH('')) 
        temp(PolNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output, you have some data that have the same ID, LastName, Firstname, ID but Car Name and Pol Number aren't. You may add `DISTINCT` and/or `GROUP BY` but you will still have multiple rows for ObjectID, LN, FN, ID because of Pol Number and Name are not the same

Comment: It will not look at the distinct POL or CAR name... What I am requesting is for each of those, display every one in it's own column based on the row.